# Не работает jstl в простом веб-приложение

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jsp, servlet, jstl

Ребят, помогите справится с jstl, 3 дня бьюсь, все перепробывала безрезультатно. Вообщем не дается мне jstl, а именно не выводит список прописанный в `<c:out value="${empList.id}"></c:out>`

Пример брала от сюда http://www.journaldev.com/2090/jstl-tutorial-jstl-tags-example

дополнительно изучала http://java-online.ru/jsp-jstl.xhtml

javax.servlet:jstl:1.2 в lib и tomcat lib включила

в решении вопроса руководствовалась: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31043869/intellij-and-jsp-jstl-cannot-resolve-taglib-for-jstl-in-tomcat7/32444393#32444393

и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253034/jstl-in-intellij-gives-errors-in-jsp

**Помогите плиз!**

собственно код:

class

```
package com.journaldev.model;

public class Employee {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String role;
    public Employee() {
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

}
```

servlet:

```
package com.journaldev.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.journaldev.model.Employee;

@WebServlet("/HomeServlet")
public class HomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.setId(1);
        emp1.setName("Pankaj");
        emp1.setRole("Developer");

        Employee emp2 = new Employee();
        emp2.setId(2);
        emp2.setName("Meghna");
        emp2.setRole("Manager");

        empList.add(emp1);
        empList.add(emp2);
        request.setAttribute("empList", empList);



        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
         pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
  <title>Home Page</title>
  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
  <style>
    table,th,td
    {
      border:1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<%-- Using JSTL forEach and out to loop a list and display items in table --%>
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Role</th></tr>
  <c:forEach items="${requestScope.empList}" var="empList">
    <tr><td><c:out value="${empList.id}"></c:out></td>
      <td><c:out value="${empList.name}"></c:out></td>
      <td><c:out value="${empList.role}"></c:out></td></tr>
  </c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

и

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>homeServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.journaldev.servlet.HomeServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>homeServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/homeServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${empList}">
  <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${item.id}"></c:out></td>
    <td><c:out value="${item.name}"></c:out></td>
    <td><c:out value="${item.role}"></c:out></td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Собственно и ваш и вариант примера были верными, просто дело оказалось в том, что браузеру необходимо было обратиться к серверу решение с кнопкой hrev="HomeServer" и вывод списка осуществился.